# Bubble sort function on array of characters in C

Tags: arrays, sorting

I am trying to use a bubble sort function with the swap function on an array of character as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

inline void SWAP(char * a, int j, int N)

{

if (j!=N) {a[j] ^= a[N]; a[N] ^= a[j]; a[j] ^= a[N];}
}

void bubblesort(char * a, int N)

{

int i, j;

for (i=N-1; i>0; i--)

for(j=0; j<i; j++)

  if (!(a[j] <= a[j+1]))
      SWAP(a,j,j+1);
}

int main()

{

int i;
int N = 0;
char * a;

a = (char *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
printf("Enter size of array:");
scanf("%d",&N);

for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
printf("%d. Enter your characters:", i+1);
scanf("%c\n", &a[i]);
}

bubblesort(a, N);

for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
printf("%c\n", a[i]);
}

printf("\n");   
return 0;

}
```

But when I run this in Linus, it works but the **bubblesort** with swap function only applies to the first two character elements of the array and the last element is left out. It seems the last element of the array is not stored in the array. Can any one help in fixing this?

Comment: The code should first read N via scanf and then use it in malloc's argument. Right now, the order is reversed and N=0 is used.

Comment: Shouldn't  the outer for loop be for (i=N; i>0; i--)